# Bank Account/User Application: Multi-threading and Synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-synchronization

for my current uni coursework, I'm meant to create a Java console application that simulates the creation of a Shared Bank Account which a maximum of 4 users have access to simultaneously. With all the resources and other multi-threading applications I found online, I was able to hook my current codes up.

Here's the mentality - Each user should have equal access to the bank account without delays, deadlocks, waiting etc. Every transaction carried out (withdrawals and deposits) should be updated to the bank balance and logged. The specific transactions to be carried out for each user are stored in an array list.

I am to make both an unsynchronized and a synchronized version of the application. I went about it by creating 4 classes - BankAccount (the bank account), BankTester (tester class to run the main app), User (the users) and UserThread (thread class for the user).

What I have right now is the unsynchronized version of the application. Any help on how I can synchronize (and improve this unsynchronized version) it would help as I am now to Multi-threading. Thanks guys.

Here's my code.

BankAccount Class:

```
public class BankAccount {

private long accountNo;
private double accountBalance;

public BankAccount() {
    this.accountNo = 9876543210L;
    this.accountBalance = 1980;
}

public void getAccountInfo() {
    System.out.println("Account Number: " + accountNo);
    System.out.println("Starting Account Balance: " + accountBalance);
}

public void getAccountBalance() {
    System.out.println("Account Balance: " + accountBalance);
}

public void deposit(double value) {
    accountBalance = (accountBalance + value);
     System.out.println("Account Balance After Deposit: " + accountBalance);
}

public void withdraw(double value) {
    accountBalance = (accountBalance + value);
    System.out.println("Account Balance After Withdrawal: " + accountBalance);
}
}
```

BankTest class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankTest {

private static double[][] transactionList = {
    {50, 10, -20, 10, -20, 20, 10, 50, -10, 10, -10, 50},
    {20, 20, -20, 50, -20, 10, 50, 50, -20, 10, 10},
    {50, 10, 10, -10, -10, 50, 20, -10, -20},
    {50, 10, -20, 20, 10, -20}
};

private static BankAccount myAccount;

private static UserThread myUser1;
private static UserThread myUser2;
private static UserThread myUser3;
private static UserThread myUser4;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (;;) {
        System.out.println("<--------- Banking Menu ----------->");
        System.out.println("1. Create Bank Account");
        System.out.println("2. Create User");
        System.out.println("3. Run Simulation");
        System.out.println("4. Exit");
        System.out.println("Enter choice: ");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        switch (in.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("<--------- Create Bank Account ----------->");
                myAccount = new BankAccount();

                System.out.println("Bank Account Created!");
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("<--------- Create User ----------->");
                System.out.println("1. User 1");
                System.out.println("2. User 2");
                System.out.println("3. User 3");
                System.out.println("4. User 4");
                userMenu();
                break;

            case 3:
                myUser1.start();
                myUser2.start();
                myUser3.start();
                myUser4.start();
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
                System.exit(0);
                break;

            default:
                System.err.println("Unrecognized option");
                break;
        }
    }
}

public static void userMenu() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    switch (in.nextInt()) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("<----- User 1 ------>");
            User user1 = new User("Saul", "Goodman", myAccount, transactionList[0]);
            myUser1 = new UserThread(user1, "User 1 Thread");
            user1.getUserInfo();
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("<-------- User 2 ------->");
            User user2 = new User("Walter", "White", myAccount, transactionList[1]);
            myUser2 = new UserThread(user2, "User 2 Thread");
            user2.getUserInfo();
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("<-------- User 3 ------->");
            User user3 = new User("Jessie", "Pinkman", myAccount, transactionList[2]);
            myUser3 = new UserThread(user3, "User 3 Thread");
            user3.getUserInfo();
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("<-------- User 4 ------->");
            User user4 = new User("Hank", "Schrader", myAccount, transactionList[3]);
            myUser4 = new UserThread(user4, "User 4 Thread");
            user4.getUserInfo();
            break;

        default:
            System.err.println("Unrecognized option");
            break;
    }
}

public static void runSimulation(User u) {
    double[] tList = u.getTransactionList();
    BankAccount ba = u.getBankAccount();

    for (int i = 0; i < tList.length; i++){
        if(tList[i] < 0) {
            ba.withdraw(tList[i]);
        } else{
            ba.deposit(tList[i]);
        }
        u.getName();
        ba.getAccountBalance();
    }
}
}
```

User class:

```
public class User {

private String name;
private String surname;
private BankAccount bankAccount;

private double[] transactionList;

public User(String n, String s, BankAccount bA, double[] tL) {
    this.name = n;
    this.surname = s;
    this.bankAccount = bA;
    this.transactionList = tL;
}

public void getName() {
    System.out.println("Name: " + this.name);
}

public double[] getTransactionList(){
    return transactionList;
}

public void getSurname() {
    System.out.println("Surname: " + this.surname);
}

public void getUserInfo() {
    System.out.println("Full name: " + this.name + " " + this.surname);
}

public BankAccount getBankAccount() {
    return bankAccount;
}   
}
```

UserThread class:

```
public class UserThread extends Thread {

private User u;

public UserThread(User u, String name) {
    super(name);
    this.u = u;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    BankTest.runSimulation(this.u);
}
}
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: So you want me to ask a specific question?

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of semaphores in order to control the access to critical section. I guess that every user could access to their `getAccountInfo()` but other methods like `withdraw` or `deposist` should have some control if two users have access to the same bank account.

Also in your `getAccountInfo()` you have this:

```
public void getAccountInfo() {
    System.out.println("Account Number: " + accountBalance);
    System.out.println("Starting Account Balance: " + accountBalance);
}
```

But should be like this:

```
public void getAccountInfo() {
    System.out.println("Account Number: " + accountNo);
    System.out.println("Starting Account Balance: " + accountBalance);
}
```

**Edit:**

If you have only one user accessing a bank account, then you don´t need to control anything. However, imagine that in a bank account we have $100 of balance. If two users try to `withdraw` at "the same time", then both will get $100. So, you should control that behavior. The use of `semaphores` will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Semaphores? Never heard of that to be honest. Let me research on it now.

Comment: I've read a bit on it, so there should be a variable to control the 4 users that have access to withdrawing or depositing?

Comment: @AuduIbrahim Right! I updated my answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks man, I guess that might be too advanced for my level. However, I will continue researching on how to implement the semaphores!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Any help on how I can ... improve this unsynchronized version

Generally, when a method begins with `get` or `set`, that method should *return* or set a value, respectively.  Your `get` methods merely print to the console.  Assuming that behavior wasn't explicitly stated in the assignment, I would revise them so they return the values indicated in the name:

```
public double getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNo;
}

public double getAccountBalance() {
    return accountBalance;
}
```

You can print out those details *after* you retrieve them from the `BankAccount` instance.  If you like, you can wrap those interactions in some sort of `BankingSession` class.

Does the assignment specify how you should deal with transactions that would lead to a negative balance?  If users are allowed to have a negative balance, then `deposit` and `withdraw` should never fail.  But if they can't, you should signal whether a transaction succeeds or not.  There are a couple ways to do this.  One would be to change the return type from `void` to `boolean` for the `withdraw` method, and return `true` only if the withdraw completed successfully (meaning there were sufficient funds available).  Otherwise, return `false`.  Another option would be to throw an exception (like a custom `InsufficientFundsException`) if the transaction cannot complete.

> Any help on how I can synchronize it

There are only two methods that modify the state of a bank account: `withdraw` and `deposit`.  Since you are calling these independently of each other (each deposit or withdrawal is an independent action), you just need to ensure that only one of those can occur at a time.  It will be sufficient to add the `synchronized` keyword to the method declarations, e.g.:

```
public synchronized void deposit(double value) { ... }
public synchronized void withdraw(double value) { ... }
```

Comment: Users aren't allowed to have a negative balance, so I guess there should be an if statement in the withdraw method(in the BankAccount class)?

Comment: Or a try and catch?

Comment: This is what I did incase there's a negative balance, does this work?

            public synchronized void withdraw(double value) {
            if (accountBalance > 0) {
            System.out.println("Amount Withdrawn: " + (int) -(value));
            System.out.println("Current balance: " + (accountBalance = 
    (accountBalance + value)));
        }     else {
          System.out.println("Insufficient Balance!!!");
        }
    }

Comment: A couple thoughts: (1) do a sanity check on `value` -- is it a positive number?  (2) In general, a function that is designed to perform an operation should not print its results to the console; just return a success or failure code, and let the caller print the results if necessary.

Comment: I don't know how I'm gonna implement 1. For 2, in the else statement, a 'return false'?

Comment: Wait, or a 'return false;' without the else declaration?

Comment: Hey man, I've tried different methods for the handling of insufficient funds during withdrawals, but none of them are working.